I need to download a file from s3 bucket I am using spring boot, where file name has %20 in it
I need it download a file from s3 bucket which has a name ayush%20inline.txt , when I generate presigned link it creates problem with encoding as %20 means space. I need a fix for this without renaming the file
I tried content disposition but didn’t work

To download a file from an S3 bucket using Spring Boot, including handling file names with %20. Replace %20 with actual space.
Here the logic
enter code here

@Value("${aws.s3.bucketName}")
private String bucketName;
private final S3Client s3Client;

@Autowired
public S3Service(S3Client s3Client) {
    this.s3Client = s3Client;
}

public void downloadFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String decodedFileName = fileName.replaceAll("%20", " ");

    Path filePath = Paths.get("path/to/save/" + decodedFileName);

    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(fileName)
            .build();

    S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
    ResponseInputStream responseInputStream = s3Object.responseInputStream();

    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath.toFile())) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = responseInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

